# How to get rid of these black lines?

Tags: modeling

Hey it's my first time using Blender and these black lines are around all my light's and certain object's, how do i get rid of them without hiding the light/object :) (a few pics below)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Toggle viewport overlays. Top right corner of the viewport.
[image]

Comment: Default shortcut should be Alt+Shift+Z